# all he did was "ask" or "asking"?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, present-participles

"asking" - In this case this kind of language element is called gerund, right?

In high school my teacher firmly told us two verbs can never be together (25 years later I can still remember her angry face).

But I do see a lot of sentences like this, in some literature:

> All he did was ask a question.

I am pretty sure my English teacher wouldn't be happy with this and would put a big "X" next to it. She told us you either convert the latter verb to an infinitive or a gerund, so it is either:

> All he did was asking a question.

or:

> All he did was to ask a question.

So is the first writing grammatically right? And if it is, is there any difference in meaning of the three sentences?

Comment: Your English teacher was trying to point you in the right direction, but English has so many exceptions that rules become almost meaningless as you develop a good ear for normal, idiomatic usage. Both your first and third example are idiomatic (the first perhaps more than the third; I haven't looked at a Google Ngram to see), while your second example is *not* idiomatic, as I think you already know. However, by rearranging the word order, "Asking a question was all that he did," that sentence becomes acceptable as well. Your English is very good. Read all you can to improve even more!

Comment: P. S. Yes, the first sentence is grammatically correct, and there is no difference in meaning between it and the third sentence.

Comment: The predicative complement here can only be an infinitival: _All he did was ask a question_. The bare infinitival is restricted to cases where the subject NP contains "do" in a relative clause, as in your example, but "to" can optionally be added: _All he did was to ask a question_.

Comment: @shenkwen - Here is a light-hearted article on gerunds and participles that is much easier to read than wading through all the conflicting comments attached to the EL&U entry on the same subject: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/participles-and-gerunds I hope you enjoy it.

Comment: (I rolled back someone else's extensive edits to preserve the original question as much as possible, adding a space, changing minor punctuation, and adding the word "infinitive." I hope this is acceptable to @shenkwen.)

Comment: Thank you! @MarkHubbard. So I not only learned something about gerund but also leaned some new terms like infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  And an English teacher wouldn't put a big "X" next to it. He will instead be happy that you know better than others. Because it's acceptable in English to use  "bare infinitive " after "do/does/ did "   in this sort of sentences. So you can write -

1) All he did was ask a question.

or

All he did was to ask a question.

or

All he did was asking a question.

But The last one, I think, is best.

Comment: what about "go"? I often hear ppl say " I go get a drink", while my "instinct" is to say "I go to get a drink" or "I go swimming"